# python target string key count invalid syntax

Tags: python, string, syntax

Why am i getting an "invalid syntax" when i run below code. Python 2.7

```
from string import *

def countSubStringMatch(target,key):
    counter=0
    fsi=0 #fsi=find string index
    while fsi<len(target):
        fsi=dna.find(key,fsi)      
        if fsi!=-1:
           counter+=1
        else:
            counter=0
            fsi=fsi+1
        fsi=fsi+1
    #print '%s is %d times in the target string' %(key,counter)

def countSubStringMatch("atgacatgcacaagtatgcat","atgc")
```

Comment: Please fix the code formatting, use the little `101/010` button

Comment: -1 I think the minimum standard for asking questions on SO should be that the asker understands the syntax of the language, *e.g.* use of the `def` keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the line:

```
def countSubStringMatch("atgacatgcacaagtatgcat","atgc")
```

You should remove the `def`. `def` is used when defining a function, not when calling it.

Comment: apologies for asking such a simple question, beginner's mistake...thanks

Answer (score 3):

Other things wrong with your code:

1. You don't use and don't need anything in the string module. Don't import from it.
2. Don't do `from somemodule import *` unless you have a very good reason for it.
3. Your code rather slowly and pointlessly struggles on after the first time that `find` returns -1 ... your loop should include

   `if fsi == -1: return counter`

   so that you return immediately with the correct count.
4. Be consistent: you use `counter += 1` but `fsi = fsi + 1`
5. ... which reminds me: find 'PEP 8' (style guide) at www.python.org, and read it -- your space bar must be feeling unloved ;-)

HTH
John

Comment: @Baba: (1) see my edit; in problem #3, should return `counter`, not `0` (2) problem #6: calculate `len(dna)` ONCE, before entering `while` loop

Answer (score 3):

for string count you could just do:

```
target = "atgacatgcacaagtatgcat"
s = 'atgc'
print '%s is %d times in the target string' % (s, target.count(s))
```